# Hide iframe from main window

Tags: javascript, html

I have 2 `<iframe>` on my main HTML form.

These `<iframe>` are loaded from different external domains. Sometime external server goes offline and user see `The page can't be dispayed`  message on my page.

**Is there a way to hide these `<iframe>` when target server is not available?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `onload` event to display iframe content. Make iframe invisible by default and set visible in `onload` event,

Answer (score 0):

You could set up a listener for the `load` event and if this isn't called within a certain timespan then you hide the frame..